# Is a file still use by php process

Tags: linux, process

I have a 3.2G file in `/tmp` called `phpvXcoZn` and I need to remove it.
Therefore I'd like to know if it is still in use but the commands I typed returned nothing :

```bash
/tmp$ bigfile=phpvXcoZn
/tmp$ ll -h $bigfile
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data 3.2G Aug 25 09:49 phpvXcoZn
/tmp$ cd
$ sudo lsof | grep $bigfile
$ sudo fuser -avm /tmp 2>&1 | grep $bigfile
$ sudo ls -l /proc/*/fd/* 2>/dev/null | grep $bigfile
$
```

EDIT0: As @MarcusMüller suggested, I can try to unlink the file and the space usage will we freed when the file is closed but I cannot `unlink` that file belonging to `www-data` with `sudo su` :

```bash
$ sudo su www-data -c "unlink /tmp/phpvXcoZn"
This account is currently not available.
$ grep www-data /etc/passwd
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

This command worked :
`sudo -u www-data bash -c "unlink /tmp/phpvXcoZn"`

Do you other command to know if it is still in use ?

Comment: well, seems like it's not in use. Also, `rm`ing a file that is still open somewhere else has no effect on the program that has it still opened. It just can't be opened through the file name anymore – and as soon as it is closed, its storage can be freed. See `man 2 unlink`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Cannot `unlink` the file as the `www-data` user although I didn't use `su -l` to avoid using a login shell. I don't understand ?

Comment: why not simply `sudo rm /tmp/phpvXcoZn`?

Comment: (it's very likely that it's intentional that `www-data` cannot be used through su, probably a secure linux rule that blocks this, and it's a good thing.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller This worked : `sudo -u www-data bash -c "unlink /tmp/phpvXcoZn"`. Thanks. Can you please convert your first comment to an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: that is super awkward. You're becoming super user, who can delete the file, to then become www-data, to then call bash to call `unlink`. Where your superuser could directly have called `rm`, as in exactly the example I gave you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I wanted `www-data` to delete its own file :). It's the only solution I found for a `nologin` user.

Comment: aside from literally the command line I proposed, you mean.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, my `sudo -u www-data bash -c ...` along with the `unlink` command you proposed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rm`ing a file that is still open somewhere else has no effect on the program that has it still opened. It just can't be opened through the file name anymore – and as soon as it is closed, its storage can be freed. See `man 2 unlink`.